# Problema margin-top en elemento padre

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente problema, es que a la hora de aplicarle un margin top a un h1 que esta dentro de un div, cuando se lo aplico, en vez de ser al H1 se le aplica al div

```
  <div id="encabezado">
      <h1>Usuarios activos</h1>
  </div>
```

/* CSS */

```
#encabezado h1{

    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

EDITO: para agregar los estilos del contenedor #encabezado

```
#encabezado
{
    position: relative;
    height: 6vh;
    background-color: darkturquoise;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eso pasa por la posición relativa de parte del encabezado. te aconsejaría utilizar un padding en el `encabezado` para obtener lo que estas buscando.

ej :

```css
#encabezado {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    background-color: darkturquoise;
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px; /*top: 20px, rigth: 0px, bottom: 0px y left:20px*/
}
h1{
  background: blue;
}  
#encabezado2 {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    background-color: darkturquoise;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 20px; /*top: 5px, rigth: 0px, bottom: 5px y left:20px*/
}
#encabezado3 {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    background-color: darkturquoise;
    padding: 0 0 20px 20px; /*top: 0px, rigth: 0px, bottom: 20px y left:20px*/
}
```

```html
<div id="encabezado">
   <h1>Usuarios activos</h1>
</div>

<div id="encabezado2">
   <h1>Usuarios activos</h1>
</div>

<div id="encabezado3">
   <h1>Usuarios activos</h1>
</div>
```

otra cosa que podrías hacer es utilizar la posición `absolute` en el h1

```css
*{
  margin : 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
#encabezado {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: darkturquoise;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
h1{
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
}  
#h1-2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 3px;
  left: 300px;
}
#h1-3 {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  top: 50px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="encabezado">
   <h1>Usuarios activos</h1>
   <h1 id="h1-2">usuorios activos 2</h1>
   <h1 id="h1-3">usuorios activos 3</h1>
</div>
```

la tercera posibilidad es poner un `overflow: hidden` al elemento padre, pero ojo, en este caso visto tu altura `height: 6vh` corres el riesgo de no ver el overflow ósea el tag `h1`

ejemplo funcionante de la tercera opción :

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#encabezado {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    background-color: darkturquoise;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 20px; 
}
h1{
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="encabezado">
      <h1>Usuarios activos</h1>
  </div>
```

ejemplo con el error que te citaba :

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#encabezado {
    position: relative;
    height: 6vh;
    background-color: darkturquoise;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 20px; 
}
h1{
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="encabezado">
      <h1>Usuarios activos</h1>
  </div>
```

aunque tienes que tener presente que si el `#encabezado` no tiene la necesidad de estar en posición relativa, te conviene dejarlo estático.

De los ejemplos que te hice te recomiendo utilizar el primero, ósea el `padding` que retengo sea mas elegante.

espero que te sea de ayuda, éxitos

Comment: Gracias, muy cierto lo que dices, todas las opciones que diste lo solucionaban, opte por aplicarle el padding

Comment: @BrianHernandez me alegra que te halla servido, igualmente te aconsejo de tener cuidado con las medidas de viewport, es mas simple utilizar porcentajes o pixeles, visto que en el viewport de un celular un `6vh` no se percibe casi a menos que no lo cambies con los media query, pero igual complican un poco el asunto, exitos

Answer (score 2):

Al realizar el codigo, ejecuta lo que pides, tambien puedes intentar al principio del codigo eliminar los margin y padding por defecto del navegador.

Otra recomendación es que puedes usar el "inspeccionar elemento" que trae el navegador por defecto y añadirle bordes a tu elemento para saber que haces con exactitud.

Espero te sirva.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#encabezado
{
    position: relative;
    height: 6vh;
    background-color: darkturquoise;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#encabezado h1{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
     <div id="encabezado">
        <h1>Usuarios activos</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes solucionar también agregando al contenedor padre un overflow: hidden

```css
#encabezado{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```